# UIPageControl with iPad SplitView for a magazine

Tags: ios, ipad, uisplitviewcontroller, uipagecontrol

I'm creating a magazine using the SplitView feature with each article at the left, then to navigate the pages I added a UIPageControl.

This works PERFECTLY when vertical, but when horizontal the PageControl is hidden. I'm assuming it's either some "autoRotate" code or something in the nib...BUT WHAT???

Comment: Vertical? Horizontal? Can you clarify whether Portrait or Landscape?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure it's hidden because the detail view gets cut off at the bottom when the screen is turned. See if you can move the UIPageControl up the page when the screen goes to the horizontal mode and then move it back when the screen goes to the vertical mode.